# Hiding the first item of an ASP.NET Repeater causes error: not a valid identifier

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, row, repeater, show-hide

I'm new in web developing and i'm kind of having a problem with hiding the first row of a `Repeater`. i know that this is kind of a simple problem but i dont know what is wrong with my codes. I have found a lot of articles and some forums with same problem but it just wont work with my code.

Im encountering this error:  'div1-row' is not a valid identifier.

Please help and thank you in advance.

```
<div id="div1">
        <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="div1-row" class="div1-row" runat="server">
                    <div class="div1-class">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Mfg").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div1-class">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Qty").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div1-class">
                            <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("Availability").ToString%>
                    </div>
                    <div class="div1-class">
                        <%# CType(Container.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("QtyRange").ToString%>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </div>

 Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound
    If e.Item.ItemIndex = 0 Then
        e.Item.FindControl("div1-row").Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** A control [`ID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.control.id%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is valid only if you use:

- combinations of alphanumeric characters and the underscore character ( _ ) are valid values for this property. Including spaces or other invalid characters will cause an ASP.NET page parser error

So `ID="div1-row"` is not allowed, use `ID="div1_row"` instead.

Old answer:

Why don't you make the complete first `RepeaterItem` invisble?

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound
    e.Item.Visible = e.Item.ItemIndex <> 0
End Sub
```

Note that the `ItemIndex` property   only applies to data items in the `Repeater` control. The `ItemType` property must be set to `ListItemType.Item`, `ListItemType.AlternatingItem`, `ListItemType.SelectedItem`, or `ListItemType.EditItem`.

So it works for example not for the `Header` if you use a `HeaderTemplate`.

Comment: hi tim, thanks for your immediate reply but im still having the same error... 'div1-row' is not a valid identifier... is there something wrong with the name i used? i dont really understand the error if it is pointing to the <div> as not the valid identifier...

Comment: @user3590797: have you recognized that i have edited my answer already?

Comment: hi tim, it working fine now.. thanks a lot... now i understand that since it is now in server-side... a different naming convention is being applied...

Comment: hi tim, im so sorry i have another question but still related to the subject above. what happens is that it is hiding the first row of the repeater but when it is on the second page, it is again hiding the first row. what i want is that to hide the real first row not the first row of every page. thanks a lot again.

Comment: hi tim, no need to answer, ive got it. :)